# adding a linebreak between tags

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I have `xml` file which will be read and displayed As `.html` page. The xml looks something like

```
  <title>Title Text</title>
    <text>
    <![CDATA[ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.]]>
    </text>
```

Now the problem is when we read this xml file and display it as html we don't have any `line break` between title and text.

What will be the best way to add line break in xml tags?

Comment: add CSS styling for specific nodes?

Comment: Well, as you aim for HTML output I suggest you turn that into an X(HT)ML document and you then insert a `<br />` element to place the HTML line-break? Is this what you're asking for?

Answer (score 0):

is the standard line break for HTML and will work in xml as well.

I know that &#xD also breaks a line in xml but I am unsure if it breaks a line in HTML. I hope this helps.

Title Text

should solve the problem for you I hope :) If not, truly sorry...

Comment: ulg. damn html tags    < br > is the standard line break

Comment: < title >Title Text< / title >  < br >
    < text >
    < ! [CDATA[ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.]]  >
    <  / text >